# Install cocoa pods, where is the root of the xcode application project directory located?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, terminal, cocoapods

Install the cocoa pods, wondering where is the root Xcode application project directory located.

Please see attached.

Screen shots of Xcode project path and terminal.

[image: Xcode Project Path]

[image: Terminal]

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `cd Documents/Xcode\ Project`

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need help in escaping spaces.

In Shell commands you should properly escape if there is a space in path.

Your directory `Xcode Project` contains a space in the middle. Use.

```
cd Documents/Xcode\ Project
```